# How to divide text from database between several columns in markup

Tags: html, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to transfer the text of the article to the **view**. The text distributed over three columns, something like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
   </div>
</div>
```

But, how can I divide the text between that columns in the markup, when it comes from database?

Comment: You could either have 3 columns in your database to hold each paragraph of text, or you could store all of the data in one textfield and get a subtring at each different breakpoint when you pull the data back from the db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

The first solution uses 3 database columns to hold your data

```
----------------------------------
               POSTS 
----------------------------------
post_id                         PK
column_1                        TEXT
column_2                        TEXT
column_3                        TEXT
```

Query : `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id=your_id` will return an array holding the id of the post as well as each of your columns, if you fetch an associative array in your HTML you can do

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="col4"><?php echo $text['column_1'] ?></div>
     <div class="col4"><?php echo $text['column_2'] ?></div>
     <div class="col4"><?php echo $text['column_3'] ?></div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:**

The second solution uses 1 database column to hold all the text and then splits on a given length

```
----------------------------------
               POSTS 
----------------------------------
post_id                         PK
post_data                       LONGTEXT
```

Query : `SELECT post_data FROM posts WHERE post_id=your_id` will return an array holding post data, you can then do

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="col4"><?php echo subtr($text['post_data'], 0, 250) ?></div>
     <div class="col4"><?php echo subtr($text['post_data'], 251, 500) ?></div>
     <div class="col4"><?php echo subtr($text['post_data'], 501, 750) ?></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.